# ¿Cómo puedo obtener 2 columnas de una misma tabla SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Queria saber si me pueden ayudar con la siguiente consulta de SQL. quiero saber cual usuario tiene la mayor edad (eso ya lo conseguí como verán en la imagen) pero además quiero que me muestre el nombre del usuario. La columna de nombres se llama `nombre_lectores`
los registros están en la misma tabla!

Esta es la consulta que me da la edad mayor pero necesito que también figure el nombre de usuario

```
select max(date_part('year',age(fecha_nacimiento_lectores)))
from lectores
```

Comment: ¿Y si hay dos personas con la misma edad máxima?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar una CTE (WITH) para obtener lo que necesitas, por ejemplo:

```
WITH sub as (
select max(date_part('year',age(fecha_nacimiento_lectores))) as mayor
from lectores
)

SELECT nombre_lectores,fecha_nacimiento_lectores 
FROM lectores 
WHERE fecha_nacimiento_lectores=(select mayor from sub)
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Realizar la conversión correspondiente en el `WHERE`

```
WITH sub as (
select max(date_part('year',age(fecha_nacimiento_lectores))) as mayor
from lectores
)

SELECT nombre_lectores,fecha_nacimiento_lectores 
FROM lectores 
WHERE date_part('year',age(fecha_nacimiento_lectores))=(select mayor from sub)
```

Comment: Me sale este erro:

ERROR:  el operador no existe: date = double precision
LINE 8: WHERE fecha_nacimiento_lectores=(select mayor from sub)
                                       ^
HINT:  Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 198

Comment: Olvidé hacer la conversión, pero en la actualización de la respuesta la puse, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bastante cómoda es usar (Postgres v10 o superior) es mediante `row_number()`, la cual nos enumera las filas, por ejemplo por los años de forma descendente, esto quiere decir que la fila con el numerador = 1 será el lector con mayor edad, solo restaría usar una subconsulta o un expresión de tabla para obtener los datos:

```
with cte as (
    select l.*
           date_part('year',age(l.fecha_nacimiento_lectores))) as años,
           row_number over (order by age(l.fecha_nacimiento_lectores) desc) as Rn
           from lectores l
)
select *
       from cte
       where Rn = 1
```